# Как игнорировать None при конвертации даты?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, обработка-данных

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEP_DATE': [4274696742, None, -1544861678, 48960604955]})
```

Преобразовывается так:

```
df["DEP_DATE"] = (df["DEP_DATE"].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))))
```

Должно получиться:

```
0    2105-06-17 15:45:42
1    nan
2    1921-01-17 21:45:22
3    3521-07-02 16:02:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

df["res"] = pd.PeriodIndex(
    [DT.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if pd.notna(x) else np.nan
     for x in df["DEP_DATE"]], 
    freq="D")
```

результат:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
       DEP_DATE         res
0  4.274697e+09  2105-06-17
1           NaN         NaT
2 -1.544862e+09  1921-01-17
3  4.896060e+10  3521-07-02

In [26]: df.dtypes
Out[26]:
DEP_DATE      float64
res         period[D]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо. Еще момент, а как правильно сконвертировать(округлить) если у меня во fame есть не только целые но и float  (48960604955.0)

Comment: @gijarak657, а в чем проблема с флоатами? `DT.utcfromtimestamp(x)` -  должен нормально отрабатывать с флоатами...

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибка была в другом месте, с float все в порядке.